# How to append the value of a neighbouring cell to a list, based on the current cell's value?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Let's suppose that colA contains names of employees. ColB contains a value 'clocked in' or an empty value " " if they are not at work.
How do I loop through colB to look for the empty cells and then append the corresponding name from colA to a list (or array?)?
At the end I want to return this list and show it on the screen (or serve it to another script). 
This is an example description but the script will deal with the same premise in my actual data.

My first attempts resulted in this little thing (at least, this is the idea, but it doesnt work, still a newbie in this):

```js
function getAbsEmployees() {
    
  var absent = [];
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('clocking in');
  var status = sheet.getRange(112, 2, 10, 1).getValues(); //colB
  Logger.log(status) //no problem up until now
  
  for (var i = 0; i < status.length; i++) {
    
    if (status[i][1] === "") {
          
    absent.push(status[i][0]); //corresponding value from colA is added to list
    }
  }
  
  return( absent );  
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(absent); //Logger.log does the same here, obviously
  
}
```

Comment: You need to know what your code is doing.  The way to know what your code is doing is to use `Logger.log()`.  There is no `length` property of the range class:  You are using `r1.length`  which won't work.  So, you could log `Logger.log('r1.length: ' + r1.length)` and then from the code editor choose View, and Logs, and look at the print out of the result.  You'll see the result.  Please read the [troubleshooting guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting)

Comment: @Norbert Sandy Good has given you some good advice, Norbert. Using `Logger.log()` can very helpful in establishing the values of variables at different stages, even within loops and troubleshooting generally. And its NOT a newbie tool. I've been coding for a while, but I find I use i use Logger at some stage just about every time I have to build some code.

Comment: any code after `return( absent );` is never executed.

Comment: @tehhowch you are right. I was probably asleep when I wrote it. You're a good sport

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a custom function place this =getAbsEmployees() in any cell outside the range of employee names.

The custom function looks like this.

```
function getAbsEmployees() {

  var absent = [];
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('clocking in');
  var names = sheet.getRange(1,1,12,2).getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    if( names[i][1] === "" ) absent.push(names[i][0]);
  }

  return( absent );
}
```

Comment: I dont really understand why I should use it as a custom function and put it into a cell (which throws and 'unknown' error), when all I want is to collect the names and send them over to another script as a list (or just print it).
Another problem is that the _for loop_ doesn't even get executed. By putting Log.logger to different places, I identify the correct values of 'names', but cannot push values into absent. What is more, It doesnt even print an empty list of 'absent' at the end. Do you have anything else in mind to help me?

Comment: @Norbert, you can do with the return list what ever you want.  I only wanted to show that if you use it as a custom function it will display the list in the spreadsheet cell below formula.  I tested it and it works for me.

Comment: @Norbert, can you replace your original code above with your latest version?

Comment: I edited the code to the latest version. I also inserted the actual range that Im using in my data (which doesnt really matter I suppose but maybe there is sth wrong?).

Comment: @Norbert, I'm not sure what is in which column but I thought last time name was in A and absence in B.  Now you are getting column B only.  getRange(112, 2, 10, 1) is start at row 112 column B thru row 121 only 1 column so names[i][1] is undefined not "". names[i][0] is what ever is in column B.

Comment: yes you were right all along. I was trying to iterate through B and then if the condition applies, get the value from A. Now I can see, that this setup was impossible to execute (but maybe [-1] could have done the trick?).
So now I try to get range from colA, then go see what is in colB with r1[i][1] and then get value from A with r1[i][0]. Am I correct?

Comment: but in this case: log(r1[i][0]) results in the correct value = name; but log(r1[i][1]) results in undefined. Can you tell why?

Comment: @Norbert, right, you could simply change to getRange(112,1,10,2).  Get columns A and B.  When you getValues you get a 2 dimensional array.  In your case 10 rows 2 columns A&B.  Each row is the first index and each column the second.  Arrays are 0 based so status[0][0] is the first row, first column or name 1.  status[0][1] is the first row, second column or absence 1.

Comment: yes of course! Now I feel stupid because this is basics of data manipulation, and it just didnt click in my head. Thanks a lot for your patience.